# Angular 2: How to implement hover contextual menu functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I would like to implement a component that behave like the Google Inbox hover contextual menu:

[image: hover contextual menu]

Wondering how to implement it on a way it can be reused, my main worries are:

1. How should I manage to show/hide it properly?
2. How can I arrange it positioning properly?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably add a bit of code inside the menu-item component, which would trigger `display: block` and `display: none` on hover. If you're using `*ngFor` for displaying the menu items it looks like the easiest way to accomplish what you want.

Guessing your code looks like:

```
<ul class="menu-list">
    <li *ngFor="let item of menu.items" class="menu-item">
        <span class="content"> <!-- content --> </span>
        <span class="date-and-check"> <!-- date and check mark --> </span>
        <span class="submenu"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then CSS would look similar to this:

```
.menu-list .menu-item {
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    height: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }

 .menu-list .menu-item date-and-time {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
 }

 .menu-list .menu-item .submenu {
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    display: none;
 }

.menu-list .menu-item:hover {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.menu-list .menu-item:hover .date-and-time {
    display: none;
}

.menu-list .menu-item:hover .submenu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```